# Subset a data frame by excluding missing cases AND certain values

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I have a dataset where my key Variable is scored from 1 to 10 and data exists for all but one case for this variable. I want to analyse data with scores equal or above 8 and ignoring the one missing case.

I managed to do the above by subsetting TWICE but ideally I would like to do all of this in one command.

Data2<-Data1[(Data1$Variable>=8),]

Data3<-Data2[!is.na(Data2$Variable),]

How can I combine the above to keep things simple?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the tidyverse package and the `filter()` function quite easily:

```
library(tidyverse)

Data2 <- filter(Data1, Variable >= 8, !is.na (Variable))
```

Comment: Awesome! You could "accept" my answer if it worked (by clicking on the check mark next to the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in)